# Литература по работе с компьютером на низком уровне

Tags: память

Хотелось изучить компьютер на низком уровне. Сам являюсь back-end разработчиком. Прочитал книгу «Код. Тайный язык информатики», но, к сожалению, не получил удовлетворения. Хотелось бы изучить байты, биты, поработать с ними напрямую. Больше интересует память компьютера (RAM), так как именно с памятью приходится работать программисту. Как именно записываются туда данные? Что такое адрес в памяти?

Подскажите литературу и статьи на эту тему.

Comment: Фундаментальная книга: Таненбаум "Архитектура компьютера".

Comment: вы хотите для образования получить представление о многочисленных уровнях абстрации между железом и моделью, используемой в высокоуровневых языках программирвания? Или вы хотите практические задачи на выбранном устройстве (каком?) решать? В сторону: *"хотелось бы изучить байты, биты"* -- после прочтения "Код. Тайный язык информатики" как вы себе байты, биты представляете? чего конкретно не хватает?

Answer (score 2):

Ну если вам нужны байты и биты, то вот: [Цифровая схемотехника
и архитектура компьютера](http://easyelectronics.ru/files/Book/digital-design-and-computer-architecture-russian-translation.pdf)